# Excel Fiscal Week Calculator

Tags: excel, vba, date, week-number

I've been working on solving this for a few hours now and keep hitting a wall.  I am very close but having small detail errors.  Currently I am using =weeknum in excel vba to dynamically create a row and receiving a #NUM! error.  It seems to work when I reference a cell but when I manual enter a date I get type mismatch errors and varies other errors.  The date format i am using is 6/3/2013

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you for your time!

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim xDate As Double
    Dim ReturnType As Integer

    TotalRowCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sap").UsedRange.Rows.count
    Set entryDateRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sap").Range("G2:G" & TotalRowCount)
'my attempt at setting the datatype for the row, I dont think this is needed, but was one solution I saw
    'Range("M2:M" & TotalRowCount).NumberFormat = "@"
'create a collumn to hold the fiscal week output
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sap").Range("M1") = "FW"

    For Each test In entryDateRange
        CurrentRow = test.Row
        fw_calc = Application.Evaluate("=WEEKNUM(G" & CurrentRow & "," & ReturnType & ")")
        ' In place of (G" & CurrentRow.. etc I would prefer to use test if possible
        Worksheets("sap").Cells(CurrentRow, 13) = fw_calc
    Next test
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fw_calc = Application.WeekNum(test, ReturnType)
```

but you haven't given `ReturnType` a value so it has its default value of 0, which is not an acceptable value. If omitted it defaults to 1 (Sunday) the day the week begins.

Answer (score 1):

OK I see your problem. Try using the following line:

```
fw_calc = Application.Evaluate("=WEEKNUM(DATE(" & Year(test.value) & "," & Month(test.value) & ", " & Day(test.value) & "))")
```

To explain more clearly, the `WEEKNUM()` function wants an excel serial date, so we need to create one first. The function to do that with is `DATE()`, which requires a separate year, month and day (in that order). So we use the VBA functions `Day()`, `Month()` and `Year()` to parse out the three components from your date cell (`test`), then pass them in to the `DATE()` function like so:

```
"DATE(" & Year(test.value) & ", " & Month(test.value) & ", " & Day(test.value) & ")"
```

This returns the date serial. Then we pass that serial as the argument to `WEEKNUM` to get the week number. Looks a bit awkward, but you get the idea.